# Clicking programmatically on the arrows of html inputs (type="number")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Supposing i have an input element, in my html code, of type number and two buttons:

```js
function downFunction(id) {
  let inputField = document.getElementById(id);
  // How to increment the value?
  log("Log from downFunction", inputField)
}

function upFunction(id) {
  let inputField = document.getElementById(id);
  // How to decrement the value?
  log("Log from upFunction", inputField)
}

function log(message, element) {
  console.log(message);
  console.log(element);
  console.log("\n");
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="inputFieldId" min="1" max="10" value="10">

<input type="button" id="downButton" onclick="downFunction('inputFieldId')" value="-"/>
<input type="button" id="upButton" onclick="upFunction('inputFieldId')" value="+" />
```

Is possible to increment/decrement the value of `inputFieldId` using javascript, or eventually jQuery, respectively by clicking on `upButton` and `downButton`?

I don't mean getting the current value of the field and re-setting the new value after doing `++` or `--` operations.
I mean by clicking directly on the arrows buttons.

To better understand, doing something of similar to this:

```
let inputField = document.getElementById(id);  
inputField[0].arrowUp.click();  
inputField[0].arrowDown.click();
```

Comment: That is probably impossible.

Comment: Just get a reference to the input and set the value. No clicking required.

Comment: Yes, i know that's the right way but i was curious to know it was possible clicking on the arrows :)

Comment: But why do you want so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `stepUp` and `stepDown` methods on `input[type=number]` HTMLElement

[stepUp Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_number_stepup.asp)
[stepDown Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_number_stepdown.asp)

```js
function stepUp() {
  document.getElementById('input').stepUp();
}

function stepDown() {
  document.getElementById('input').stepDown();
}
```

```html
<input id=input type=number min=1 max=10>
<button onclick="stepUp()">+</button>
<button onclick="stepDown()">-</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you for your help! I wasn't able to find the documentation. Thank you for the link reference too :)

Comment: @RobertoManfreda: It's an interesting API, but it doesn't simulate a click on the buttons. Were you actually hoping to increment/decrement in a manner that respects the `min` and `max`?

Comment: Yes, but why??? Running the code snippet all is working... I modified the original snipped of my answer simply adding the stepUp() and stepDown() calls and all is working! o.O

Comment: They are methods available on `input[type=number]` element

(https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#dom-input-stepup)

Comment: @RobertoManfreda

If you find my answer helpful, please upvote it. That would help me too.

Comment: @RobertoManfreda: I'm just basing my comment on your actual question, which is to simulate clicks, which this doesn't do. A simulated click would be represented by an event on the number input. It seems you didn't want a simulated click at all, but wanted automatic clamping to the given range.

Answer (score 0):

**You won't be able to programmatically click the arrows of an `input type="number"`**, but you don't have to because that's not what you actually want to do. What you want to do is the same action that would have happened if the user had clicked those arrows. So, you can just initiate that code yourself. In this case, just adjust the `value` of the element.

Comment: *"that's not what you actually want to do"* Unless it actually is. What if they want to simulate actual user interaction?

Comment: @ziggywiggy To what end?

Comment: Sorry but you answer it's not completely true... there can be some cases where i need to do that...

Comment: That would depend on the intent of the individual. At the very least, you'd want representation of the event in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Get the up/down button coordinates.

```
$('#upButton').click(function (e){
    var elm = $(this);
    var xPos = e.pageX - elm.offset().left;
    var yPos = e.pageY - elm.offset().top;
​
    console.log(xPos, yPos);
});
```

Click at those coordinates.

```
var event = $.Event('click');
event.clientX = 12.796875;
event.clientY = 9;
$('.upButton').trigger(event);
```

Comment: Your snippet is not executing correctly but i think your solution can works too... even if i prefer not using jQuery for this purpose :)

Comment: Yeah I was hoping it would work but it probably depends on resolution and all that. I took it out but you can test. I did successfully get it working on my end.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use `inputElement.stepUp()` to change the value, that by itself won't fire an `input` event on the element.

So, if your code has `inputElement.addEventListener('input', () => { // do stuff})`, it will not be triggered.

However, after `.stepUp()` in your code, you can add

```
let event = new Event('input', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
});

inputElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Then the `input` event will fire on the element, as though a user entered it.

Citation: ChatGPT-4 taught me that!